# Flowtype enum actions redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype

Still having a hard time getting everything checked using Flow in my react/redux application.

When typing my actions, i get:

```
type MessageSentAction = { type: 'MSG_SENT', 
  message: string,  
}
type Action = MessageSentAction | AnotherAction;
```

Have no problems with that, but I want to replace the type MSG_SENT with a constant.

```
const actionTypes = { MESSAGE_SENT = 'MSG_SENT'}
...
type MessageSentAction = { type: ActionTypes.MESSAGE_SENT, 
  message: string,  
}
```

How can I get this to work? I don't want the action string being duplicated accross actions, reducers and types ...
The above sample gives an error: *"Ineligible value used in/as flow type annotation."*

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`typeof`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/typeof/#toc-typeof-type-syntax) operator

```
const actionTypes = { MESSAGE_SENT: 'MSG_SENT'}

type MessageSentAction = { 
  type: typeof actionTypes.MESSAGE_SENT, 
  message: string,  
}
```

Comment: Not entirely the same ... when defining all types as type: 'MSG_SENT', I'll get an error when assigning another value than the types given. When using typeof ... I could also just defined type as type: string

Comment: OK, that wasn't clear from the question. But I see you've already found the solution, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just found it ... for reference:

```
const ACTION_TYPES = { MESSAGE_SENT: 'MSG_SENT', TEST: 'test'};
type ActionType = $Values<typeof ACTION_TYPES>;

type MessageSentAction = { type: ActionType, 
  message: string,  
}

function test(t: MessageSentAction) {
  t.type = 'MSG_SENT';
}
```

When changing t.type to something not in the ACTION_TYPES values, i'll get a flow error.

This differs from previous answer where any given string would be OK